# DAX : Using USERELATIONSHIP and getting a circular dependency detected error

Tags: dax, powerquery, circular-dependency

i have 2 tables which have 2 relationships based on 2 dates :
The "daily_valus" table have several products per date which (date) is connected to the weeklies table on the 2 dates (date fin adjusted & date début adjusted). The "date début adjusted" is the active one.

[image]

I have the following formula in a new column (ctRow) of the weeklies table :

```
= calculate( COUNTROWS(daily_valus); USERELATIONSHIP(daily_valus[Détail.Date];weeklies[date fin adjusted]))
```

The formula works and is getting the right number of rows.

However, I have another add. column and i'm just refererencing the ctRow column :

```
= weeklies[ctRow]
```

then i got that error below.

[image]

Does anyone knows why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be enough to remove the dependency from all of the columns but for the date to be used in the relationship using ALLEXCEPT

```
=
CALCULATE(
    COUNTROWS( daily_valus );
    USERELATIONSHIP ( daily_valus[Détail.Date]; weeklies[date fin adjusted] );
    ALLEXCEPT( weeklies; weeklies[date fin adjusted] )
)
```

Edit:

The circular dependency happen because when we use CALCULATE, a context transition happens, to transform the current row context on the current rows for which we are evaluating the calculated column.

This means that a filter context is set on every column of the current row, including the second calculated column, that copies the ctRow, that I'll call ctRow2. But ctRows2 depends on ctRow, therefore we get the circular dependency.

To solve the circular dependency we must remove the dependency from the result of the context transition, but keeping the filter over the column that is needed for the relationship to work, that in our case it means to use ALLEXCEPT( weeklies; weeklies[date fin adjusted] ).

Comment: thanks Sergiom, works perfectly ! would you have by any chance a link to dig in a little bit further ? i'd like to understand this. Thanks !!

Comment: I'll have a deeper look at this as soon I have some spare time. Since my first test with just one relationship didn't show the circular dependency an now I'm curious to better understand why.

Comment: OK, I added the reason for the circular dependency. The fact that without the USERELATIONSHIP we dont get a circular dependency is a consequence of the optimizations that DAX can apply when a Primary Key exists, that are disabled when a USERELATIONSHIP is used.

Comment: wow, thanks, this is something i'd never think about.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve similar error by removing USERELATIONSHIP line, which was not needed in my case. So one solution should be to make the connection active and then remove this line.